# How to add labels for each bar (count on y-axis)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm currently trying to recreate image shown below. I have troubles with adding labels to each bar. I've also already searched google and SO for solutions, but I wasn't able to adapt them to my problem.
There's no need to achieve an exact 100% copy.

### Current State: Solved

[image: Current State Graphic]

### Target

[image: Target Graphic]

### Code

I've written a function 'createBarplot' which takes dataframe (obviously a data frame) and x (string/char) as parameters. Don't ask why. In any case, this is the reason for the code looking like this.

```
ggplot(dataframe, aes(x = dataframe[, x])) +
    geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), fill="#0081DB", colour="#000F83", size=2) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, breaks = seq(0, 0.6, by = 0.1)) +
    scale_x_discrete(labels = levels(dataframe[, x])) +
    labs(y = "Prozent", x = NULL) +
    ggtitle(label = attr(sampledata, "variable.labels")[do.call("getColumnIndexByName",args = list(dataframe, x))]) +
    geom_text(aes(y = ..count.. / sum(..count..),
                  label = paste0(round(..count.. / sum(..count..) * 100, 0),"%"),
                  hjust = ifelse( (..count.. / sum(..count..)) >= 0.025, 1.25, -0.25)),
              stat="count") +
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
          axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
          plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.1)) +
    coord_flip()
```

### Data

```
dataframe <- as.data.frame(x = c(5L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
                                           3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
                                           3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
                                           5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 
                                           4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
                                           4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 
                                           4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
                                           5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                           4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
                                           4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
                                           4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                           5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 
                                           3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 
                                           5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                           5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 
                                           3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("5 Sehr unzufrieden", 
                                                                                                           "4", "3", "2", "1 Sehr zufrieden"), class = "factor")

colnames(dataframe) <- "col"
x <- "col"
```

Comment: @beetroot I've provided some new data code. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: You could do `createBarplot(dataframe, x) + geom_text(aes(y=..count../sum(..count..), label=paste0(..count../sum(..count..)*100,"%")), hjust=1, stat="count")`. In general, your best option is probably to count the data beforehand instead of using stat_count two times.

Comment: @lukeA Could you explain me why this is the better choice? Could you also show me how to count it beforehand and include it in the code then? Thanks for your answer! I've adjusted my question.

Comment: @MarcBrinkmann Sure - compare the two code blocks in the answer.

Comment: I just tried the following inside the geom_text function: `hjust = if_else( (..count../sum(..count..)) >= 0.2, 1, 0)`, but I am receiving the error that the object '..count..' has not been found. Why can't I use it there? Can I only use it inside aes() ?

Comment: @MarcBrinkmann Yes, put it into aes if you want to reference variables in the data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
library(tidyverse)
dataframe %>% 
  ggplot(aes_string(x = x)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), stat = "count") + 
  coord_flip() + 
  geom_text(aes(y=..count../sum(..count..), label=paste0(..count../sum(..count..)*100,"%")), hjust=1, stat="count")
```

However, if you compare it with the pre-counted

```
dataframe %>% 
  count_(x) %>%
  mutate(n=n/sum(n)*100) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=col, y=n)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  coord_flip() + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(n, "%")), hjust=1)
```

I'd say the latter one is more readable (and for larger data sets probably faster, too). Both should give you the same result.

Comment: Could you explain how the data in the 2nd example is pasted into the ggplot function? Why is it needed to use this `n/sum(n)` in geom_text once more?

Comment: Just tried out your second solution, but I retrieved this error: `stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic.`

Comment: 2nd `n/sum(n)` isn't necessary, when I added ` mutate(n=n/sum(n)*100)` my f* o2 dsl broke again, so I lost track. Anyway: I edit it.  Both solutions work fine here - maybe update tidyverse?